# I want to create a workflow in AEM/CQ5 which will check author's permission for any dialogue change

Tags: aem

I have a profile dashboard which have Authoring capabilities to change the text/images/text color through dialog. I want to create a workflow which will allow the changes to be reflected only after the permission of one Author group.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a participant step to your workflow and configure the group which processes such requests.Refer to adobe's documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/extending/workflows/step-ref.html#Participant%20Step)